# How can I monitor a queue for when messages arrive?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I'm looking for the equivalent of FileSystemWatcher for a specific MSMQ queue. Does something like that exist or do I need to roll my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that basically what [MQReceiveMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699825%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  does? My apologies for referencing the C docs, but all of this functionality should be available to .NET. Essentially you can use this function to peek at messages in the queue:

> When reading messages, you can either peek at (not removing them) or retrieve the messages (removing them) in the queue.

And you can use it to block until a message is ready:

> Processing is blocked in the applicable thread until a message is found in the queue (this is the default setting).

Apparently you can also use this function to receive messages asynchronously, in which case it would operate much like the FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: I can just use the MessageQueue.Peek function in .NET. I didn't realize it blocked until a message arrived. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use MSMQ Triggers.  See MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

From the first paragraph:

> Message Queuing triggers allow you to associate the arrival of incoming messages at a destination queue with the functionality of one or more COM components or stand-alone executable programs. These triggers can be used to define business rules that can be invoked when a message arrives at the queue without doing any additional programming. Application developers no longer must write any infrastructure code to provide this kind of message-handling functionality.